# Save big dataset from R into temp table SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have a dataframe (`predict_prc`) with 60k rows and 2 variables (`chrt_id` and `prc`). And I need to save this dataframe into MS SQL database.

I choose the next way - create temp table, insert new values and exec the stored proc.

I tried the code below:

```
sql = paste("
            CREATE TABLE #t (chrt_id INT PRIMARY KEY,prc FLOAT)
            INSERT INTO #t
            VALUES", 
            paste0(sprintf("(%.2i, ", predict_prc$chrt_id), sprintf("%.2f)", predict_prc$predict_prc), collapse = ", ")
            ,"EXEC DM.LoadChrtPrc
            ")
```

But its too many values to insert this way.

Then I tried next code:

```
sql_create = paste("
IF (SELECT object_id('#t')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #t
END
CREATE TABLE #t (chrt_id FLOAT PRIMARY KEY, prc FLOAT)
            ")

sql_exec = paste("
                 EXEC DM.LoadChrtPrc
                 ")

channel <- odbcConnect('db.w')
create <- sqlQuery(channel, sql_create)
save <- sqlSave(channel, predict_prc, tablename = '#t', fast=TRUE, append=F, rownames=FALSE)
output <- sqlQuery(channel, sql_exec)
odbcClose(channel)
```

But i`ve got an error:

```
> save <- sqlSave(channel, predict_prc, tablename = '#t', fast=TRUE, append=F, rownames=FALSE)
Error in sqlSave(channel, predict_prc, tablename = "#t", fast = TRUE,  : 
  42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named '#t' in the database.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE "#t"  ("chrt_id" float, "prc" float)'
```

If I execute `save` without `create` then I`ve got this error:

```
> save <- sqlSave(channel, predict_prc, tablename = '#t1', fast=TRUE, append=F, rownames=FALSE)
Error in sqlColumns(channel, tablename) : 
  ‘#t’: table not found on channel
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't allow more than 1000 rows in one query.
You can insert all the values by creating chunks of 1000.
For every 1000 rows, you should create a new sql query and run it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem i have to create several temporary tables and then I inserted 1000 records per table to solve my problem.
So before you create temporary table, count the number of records you gonna put in temp table , divide by 1000 and then create a temp table as per your requirement.

This solution is for one time query solution.
If you want automate the process, use something else.

Comment: to make this answer a little different from the 2017 one, could you put bits of useful code?